# Is it safe to use /data or /vol mounted filesystem for external HDD?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, fstab

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to mount AWS EBS (or any other network drive) to one of the following:

```
/data
/vol
/some-other-folder
```

I know, that there standard directories, like:

```
/var
/etc
/mnt
/media
```

As there are no standard directory name, where to mount a such external HDD, SAN, NAS... Are there any best practices? Or I should mount it under **/mnt** or **/media** dir?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) says, that /media is for removable media, and /mnt is for Temporarily mounted filesystems. But I want to mount a permanent filesystem.

Another concern is, if I choose /data, then will I have some potential folder conflict in future? When /data can be included in Linux Filesystem Hierarchy...

Comment: `/media` is fine. You'll notice that Ubuntu mounts partitions from internal disks there. As for `/data` getting into FHS, I think you'll have years of notice before such a change hits you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally best practice is to mount the drive according to it's purpose, which is why unix systems have this standardised filing system. For example, if you are going to use the drive as a home drive then you might consider mounting it as /home. Have a look at [The linux filing system hierarchy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy.html) to see if the usage of the drive fits in here. You may want to mount it as a sub-directory within one of these locations (e.g. /opt/teamsoftware)

If the drive is for just your use then you can mount it in /media or anywhere in your home folder.

If the drive is for a shared purpose, for example a project folder, then I suggest using an unused root folder name such as /projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally used `/data` for over 5 years on Ubuntu, with no problems. While this may not be "kosher", it does what it's supposed to do.